# Uncovering variables associated with built-in functions in R

Tags: r

Is there a way (a function) to uncover all the variables associated with a function in R?

I mean eg take the *grangertest* function in the *lmtest*, ***is there a way to extract the F-Statistic values and the probabilities associated with?***

```
Granger causality test

Model 1: BO ~ Lags(BO, 1:1) + Lags(FCPO, 1:1)
Model 2: BO ~ Lags(BO, 1:1)
  Res.Df Df      F Pr(>F)
1    777                 
2    778 -1 1.4049 0.2363
```

***And/or is there a general way to do this in R?***

I'm sorry, I don't know well how to specify my question. Anyway, I hope I'm meaningful.

Thanks.

Comment: Normally `str` will give you insight, but some things may not be stored in the object, but calculated by the `print` or `summary` method for the object class.

Comment: As a general rule, start with the help page for any function. The page will tell you what values are returned, and in the case of many stats and fitting functions, will also tell you what other functions have specific methods for the object your function returns. (basically repeating what @James was getting at)